# How to install caffe in anaconda in Mac OS?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, caffe

I am trying to use caffe module with OpenCV. I am creating environment using Anaconda. I am not finding this module in Anaconda. Tried conda install caffe, it didn't work.

I am new to OpenCV and Python, please guide or provide reference on how to install caffe.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the official install documentation directly on [Caffe's site](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html). You need to compile Caffe itself, and then compile the Python wrappers.